# How to cut a wood plank to make kumiko ramrods?

Tags: cutting, cut

I'am interrested in making kumiko, but I don't know how to make wood ramrods from the wood plank ?

I have access to a table saw a ruban saw and to usual wood tools.

I'd like to know how to proceed to avoid a lot of wasted wood and preserve the rectitude of the wood.

Thank you.

Comment: It could be a translation problem, but what do you mean when you say "ramrod"? Are you just referring to the wood/material used?

Comment: We can't advise about where to purchase materials but usually you *make* the wood pieces you need for work like this, you don't buy them.

Comment: Ramrod is the word I find for french "baguette" meaning long stick of wood of rectangular section of approximatively 10 * 3 mm.

Comment: @graphus What is the good methode to make them starting from a plank of wood ?

Comment: That's what you should change your Question to ask about, that we can help you with :-)

Comment: What tools do you have?  (A table saw would make an excellent start.)

Comment: I improved my question.

Comment: You might tell us what Kumiko is. wikipedia says it a female name or a game. the more info you can include in you question the better.

Comment: Search on internet for kumiko woodcraft, for example : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3pEX07KAMI

Comment: The question's link is dead, which doesn't help.

Comment: There are collection of lattice making videos to be found at http://www.finewoodworking.com/?s=Kumiko+ There is an older book by Jay Van Arsdale called Shoji: How to Design, Build, and Install Japanese Screens with a section on  Kumiko that clear and easy to follow. The short answer is buy strips or use a powertool like a tablesaw to cut them (with an eye on safety). There are simple jigs to build that allow for the cutting parts at 30, 60, 45 degree angles. Then cut your strips to length and use the jigs to trim the ends and cut the notches.

Comment: Hi Mike Peckovich from Fine Woodworking wrote an article about Kumiko about 2 months ago. First time I'd ever heard of it. :)

Comment: Thank you for all this comments and for the link. My problem is what is the best way to cut a plank into long kumiko lattices. The video shows how to cut lattices in small pieces and the fine tuning of the edge angles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last reply to comments, I believe your are asking "What is the best way to make Kumiko strips out of a plank.

Here is a very fine tutorial/idea source for that: 
http://www.bigsandwoodworking.com/making-kumiko/

Comment: Welcome to WW.SE! Link-only answers are discouraged on StackExchange, as links tend to rot over time. Quote some relevant portions of the linked page to keep this answer relevant should the link stop working.

Comment: Fair point. Noted for future.

Comment: This answer would be improved if you'd summarize the key ideas from the tutorial.